# thread safe increment value in db

Tags: postgresql, go

I have come across a problem, not sure how to implement it with DB. I have go lang on the application side.

I have product table with column assigned as `last_port_used`. I need to assign ports to services when someone hits an api. It need to increment the `last_port_id` by `1` against its product name.

one possible solution would have been to use redis server and sync this value over there. Since we dont have redis. I wanted to achieve the same by `psql`.

I read more about locks and i think i need `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock. is this the right way to do it?

`product`

- `id`
- `name`
- `start_port //11000`
- `end_port//11999`
- `last_port_used// 11023`

How to handle it concurrently properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do simply:

```
UPDATE products SET last_port_used = last_port_used+1
WHERE   id=...
    AND last_port_used < end_port
RETURNING *
```

This will perform the update in a thread-safe manner, and only if a port number is available (last_port_used < end_port) and return the assigned port.

If you need to lock the row, you can also use SELECT FOR UPDATE.

Comment: And i need it to insert this value in some other table row. Do i need to make it a transaction?

Comment: Yes, it should be in a transaction, since if the second query fails, you also want the update to be rolled back.

Comment: I was wondering, i have like 100 ports to use. I need to store thr incremented value. Is there any way to make sure, if a counter is increased. It's stored and if some failure occurs, this get decremented and other thread use that count.

Comment: I think something like. Transaction begin - > Lock table - - > inc - > store - > if fails - > dec - > COMMIT

Comment: If pass - > commit

Comment: simpler: select for update, add 1 on application side, if pass, update to increment

Comment: Two reads can take place at the same time and one can fail? Causing gaps on incremented value?

Comment: by "if pass" I mean if there are no errors on the application side ; select for update will lock the row and wait (or timeout)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229016/discussion-between-botjr-and-bobflux).